# Clarifai Exception: Maximum attempts reached of getting a default model

Tags: java, android, clarifai

I'm getting this exception in my logs: "clarifai2.exception.ClarifaiException: Maximum attempts reached of getting a default model." which is being generated by a large number of my android app users, but I am unable to replicate the exception or determine what is causing it. Any help on how to recreate or even better prevent this exception from occurring would be very helpful.

UPDATE:
I found the issue and am able to reproduce on demand, if no internet connection is available the Clarifai library throws this exception, there is no check for network connection state within the library. I can check for network connection in my app before building the clarifai client, but if the network connection is lost after the client is built this exception is generated, any ideas on how to prevent this? Thank you.

1 - Ensure data connection to internet is available on phone.

2 - Build clarifai client in onCreate

3 - Send clarifai predict request to food model

4 - Disable wifi and mobile data connections on phone

5 - Wait 10 to 15 seconds, can navigate to other activities, then clarifai throws "Clarifai Exception: Maximum attempts reached of getting a default model" and crashes the app.

Clarifai Library class which can throw this exception is available [HERE](https://github.com/Clarifai/clarifai-java/blob/master/core/src/main/java/clarifai2/dto/model/DefaultModels.java)

I call the buildClarifaiClient method below in my onCreate of the requesting activity.

```
private void buildClarifaiClient(){

    if(clarifaiClient == null){

        clarifaiClient = new ClarifaiBuilder("KeyString")
                .client(new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                        .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                        .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                        .writeTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                        //.addInterceptor(new HttpLoggingInterceptor(logger::info).setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BASIC))
                        .build()
                )
                .buildSync();

    }

}
```

Request to Clarifai on ActivityResult after a picture is taken:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {


        if(clarifaiClient != null) {

            snapSearchActivityResult = true;

            taskClarifaiRequest = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, ClarifaiResponse<List<ClarifaiOutput<Concept>>>>() {

                @Override
                protected void onPreExecute() {


                }

                @Override
                protected ClarifaiResponse<List<ClarifaiOutput<Concept>>> doInBackground(Void... params) {
                    // The default Clarifai model that identifies concepts in images

                    // Use this model to predict, with the image that the user just selected as the input
                    return clarifaiClient.getDefaultModels().foodModel().predict()
                            .withInputs(ClarifaiInput.forImage(ClarifaiImage.of(getPicByteData())))
                            .executeSync();
                }


                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(ClarifaiResponse<List<ClarifaiOutput<Concept>>> response) {
                    //setBusy(false);
                    if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                        showErrorSnackbar(getString(R.string.clarifaiAPIContactError));

                        return;
                    }
                    final List<ClarifaiOutput<Concept>> predictions = response.get();
                    if (predictions.isEmpty()) {
                        showErrorSnackbar(getString(R.string.clarifaiAPIResultsError));

                        return;
                    }

                    List<Concept> concepts = predictions.get(0).data();

                    int conceptsSize = concepts.size();

                    Log.d("conceptsSize", String.valueOf(conceptsSize));



                    for (Concept c : concepts) {
                        // Do something with the value

                        Log.d("foodName", String.valueOf(c.name()));
                        Log.d("foodProb", String.valueOf(c.value()));

                    }

                    }

                private void showErrorSnackbar(String errorString) {
                    Snackbar.make(
                            parentLayout,
                            errorString,
                            Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG
                    ).show();
                }
            };

            taskClarifaiRequest.execute();

        } else {

            Snackbar.make(
                    parentLayout,
                    "Unable to connect to Image API, try again.",
                    Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG
            ).show();


            buildClarifaiClient();

        }
      }
```

Stacktrace:

```
Exception clarifai2.exception.ClarifaiException: Maximum attempts 
reached of getting a default model.
clarifai2.dto.model.DefaultModels.update ()
clarifai2.dto.model.DefaultModels.access$000 ()
clarifai2.dto.model.DefaultModels$1.run ()
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker 
(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run 
(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:818)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that the API key you use here doesn't have permissions for doing get model request. When you access the food model via `getDefaultModels()`, the model is first updated (via get model request) and only after that the predict request is run. If the first one fails, the second one doesn't run.

In the Java API client 2.3 which is about to be released next week, the call `getDefaultModels()` will no longer initiate get model request since most of the time you require only an ID of a default model, not the complete model data which get model request returns. Since only predict request will be performed, you will not need to have get model request permissions on your API key.

In the meanwhile, you can do one of two things. Either:

- Add **Models:Get** permission to your API key. You do this by going to the [API keys page](https://clarifai.com/developer/account/api-keys), editing your API key, clicking **ADVANCED** under **Scopes** and checking **Models:Get**. You probably already have **Predict** permission checked.
- Or use the model ID directly on the predict call. I've inserted the food default model ID (which you can also see in the `DefaultModels.java` link you posted above) into the predict call for you: `client.predict("bd367be194cf45149e75f01d59f77ba7").withInputs(...).executeSync();`.

Comment: I already have ALL scopes enabled, including GET and everything else under Advanced for my API Key. I'll try updating the predict call to use the hardcoded default food model id as you suggested. Thanks.

Comment: I found the issue and am able to reproduce on demand, if no internet connection is available the Clarifai library throws this exception, there is no check for network connection state within the library. I can check for network connection in my app before building the clarifai client, but if the network connection is lost after the client is built this exception is generated, any ideas on how to prevent this? Thank you.

Comment: Exact steps to reproduce the issue: 1 - Ensure data connection to internet is available on phone.
2 - Build clarifai client in onCreate
3 - Send clarifai predict request to food model
4 - Disable wifi and mobile data connections on phone
5 - Wait 10 to 15 seconds, can navigate to other activities, then clarifai throws "Clarifai Exception: Maximum attempts reached of getting a default model" and crashes the app.

Comment: I see, it's thrown because the model can be updated to a complete model. In the version 2.3 an exception will not be thrown in such a case anymore. You'll be able to check whether a network error occurred using `response.getStatus().networkErrorOccurred()`. Until then, I suggest you handle the exception using `try/catch` OR use the second approach I described in the answer where an exception is not thrown and you can then check for network error occurrence as I've just written.

Comment: * because this model _can't_ be updated to a complete model (since there's no network)